# Active Directory - restricting permissions for users using different (native) apps

Tags: powershell, active-directory, adal

I have an Active Directory with applications in it. I assign app roles to users in Powershell. The problem is: when they have access to one they have access to another.

I give the permission for a specific application in Powershell as in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes), but if I point them towards another application, all they have to do is click confirm on the 'This application will have access to...' screen and they have access to the application, without me giving them permission like in that article.

How do I restrict permission so that it's only one app in AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this setting and it solved the problem:

[image]